# Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and I have 2 insert queries in 2 partial views.
in other view call 2 action. But I get this error

> Error executing child request for handler '`System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper`
>   error in:
>     `@Html.Action("InsertState", "Foundation")`

When I continue, the error does not show any error in my page and the insert query works correctly, but this error is showing before this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No issue in using `ViewBag` even if you are taking values from database. Also, create a View Model composed of all your required models and then pass the main model from controller and in view use this main model

**Model**:

```
public class MainModel 
{ 
    public ModelA objModelA {get;set;}
    public ModelB objModelB {get;set;}
    public ModelC objModelC {get;set;}
}
```

**Controller**:

```
Public ActionResult ActionName()
{
   ViewBag.state=new SelectList()fdgfg); 
    return View(new MainModel());
}
```

**View**:

```
@model MainModel 
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ModelA.age)
@Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.ModelA.name)
@Html.Dropdown("state")
```

Comment: Do main model like viewmodel?

Comment: I have 4 PartialView and use ViewModel for this partial. and in my view use @html.Action("Partial1","Home")                                                                    @html.Action("Partial2", "Home") @html.Action("Partial3","Home")                                                                @html.Action("Partial4", "Home")

Comment: in partials i use viewmodel to fill dropdowns in each partial.

Comment: Do main model like viewmodel?. Add Viewmodel that you are using for dropdown to main model  - yes

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. Check the Exception Message. This might have occurred due to some error in View.

Comment: There is no error except this and my query work correct and insert my db but before insert show this error and when i click continue i see my page correctly

Comment: When this expectation occurs instead of continuing click on View Detail option and see the exception or the message

Comment: Error in View Detail :    Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.

Comment: Error in InnerException :    {"The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'MeterControl.Models.DomainModels.tblState', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'MeterControl.ViewModels.FoundationCon.LocationViewModel'."}

Comment: @mahdisdezfouli  Then I think there is some error in your View itself. Please add your code in View and Exception with screenshot if possible

Comment: Ok. then the error is in your View the model you have mentioned is MeterControl.ViewModels.FoundationCon.LocationViewModel'." and in you controller get method or post method you are passing "MeterControl.Models.DomainModels.tblState'". Make sure your controller sending model and View receiving model are same

Comment: I have drop down list in PartialView and my controller should send partialView and tblState and fill drop down list. for this reason i can not send same model and i send tblState.

Comment: Ok. Then  why do you need "MeterControl.ViewModels.FoundationCon.LocationViewModel'" model

Comment: because i use 4 form in one view (4 query insert in one view).

Comment: i bind dropdown from database

Comment: The reason for error is above one as I said. Do one thing Pass MeterControl.ViewModels.FoundationCon.LocationViewModel'" from your controller to view and then for binding the dropdwon value use ViewBag or ViewData

Answer (score 0):

This error could also arise if you have an error in your partial view. I encountered this situation when i was using a partial view in main view. i had this on the partial view

```
   <img  id="image54tr" alt="Image De l'Immobilier" src=""   "/>
```

with one more quote in the img tag and when trying to compile, get the similar error. By removing this quote and having the below tag, the problem was solved

```
    <img  id="image3im" alt="Image De l'Immobilier" src=""   />
```

This mean that when you have this type of error, first inspect your partialview to see if there is not any error before looking for another ways to solve it